# $_POST not populating after fetch

Tags: javascript, php, http-post, fetch

I have spent hours chasing this and hope someone has a simple answer.  I am using fetch to execute a routine.  The server does not seem to populate the post values.  I simplified the code to try and isolate it.  A simple html form makes js request which issues a fetch including post of username and pwd.  The values get passed to the server but the target php page has the $_POST array empty.  Code follows.  Any ideas?

**web page initiating the request**

```
***
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Who are you?</h1>
    <form action="" method=POST>
        <label>User Name</label>
        <input id=username type=text autocomplete='username' name=username>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input id=pwd type=password autocomplete='current-password' name=pwd>
        <input type=submit value="log in" onclick="login();">
    </form>
</body>
</html>***
```

**javascript fetching the response from the php page**

```
***
async function login(){
    let content = "username=buddy&pwd=xxxxxxxxx";
    let response = await fetch("http://example.com/lib/2.php",{method: "POST", body: content });
    var text = await response.text();
    if(text == 1){
        window.open("http://example.com", "_self");
    }else{
        alert(text);
    }
}***

**php page where post does not populate**
***
<?php
    echo "user name is ".$_POST['username'];
?>***
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  It turns out there was nothing wrong with the code in the first place.  The introduction of formdata working was a fluke.  On further testing, it failed as well.  In fact, execution of the code sometimes worked and sometimes did not.  I traced the problem down to the user of session_start.  I need to do more research on the use of session_start so I am not sure why it causes the problem but I suspect that the $_POST is being associated with the session id and some of the time the session ids match and the post is visible and in other cases the session ids are different and the post is missing.